Split A4 page into A7 sections
I'm given a document of A4 pages with 8 A7 sections on each page.
I need to extract the data from each A7 area of each page because they're related.
Is it possible to break each A4 in 8 A7 and go through the data?
This is the PDF file I'm dealing with: https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3.barcodegen-website.io/programada+pdf+teste.pdf
(Regarding A4/A7 paper sizes, see ISO 216 at Wikipedia.)

Is it possible to break each A4 in 8 A7 and go through the data. Are you sure you can fit eight A7s in one A4?

@g00se Yes, that's how the A-system works. One A4 page is two A5 pages, four A6 pages, eight A7 pages.

Which pdfbox version are you using, and how this sections are defined on the original page? It's just the position of text or are there some markers?

@Sören, that's all very well, but all page elements of the A4 would have to sit properly within eight A7 pages

I've updated the question including the pdf i'm dealing with. Need to go through and do stuff with each a7 block.

Splitting PDF pages raises a number of secondary issues like what will you do with half a "glyph" (or half a hyperlink) Thus internal hyperlinks will usually be discarded but perhaps externals need keeping.
We need to test for duplication of resources so a source A4 of 526 KB (539,607 bytes) may actually become slightly different as 537 KB (550,093 bytes) which sometimes is oddly smaller but here only slightly larger!

Using an image approach is not acceptable as clearly at this scale the Bar codes are likely to be destroyed.
Image Left (Notice the bad infill), Vector Right is accurate for scanning.

Cropped duplication is not always a good solution as there can be overlapping contents per page. However in this case that can be broken by a decimation into 4 x 2 pages, Seen here in facing pairs. We may also see at that stage the offsets vary and are not perfect for such splitting. Thus the source positions either need alter or the page boundary sliding in different directions.

Corrected Result as seen in Acrobat Reader etc.
mutool poster -x 4 -y 2 -r programada.pdf output.pdf

Nearest to desired cropping is
cpdf -shift-boxes "-20 0" TOTVS.pdf -o tempout1.pdf
cpdf -chop "4 2" tempout1.pdf -o tempout2.pdf
mutool trim -b MediaBox -o final.pdf tempout2.pdf

or
cpdf -shift-boxes "-20 0" TOTVS.pdf -o tempout1.pdf
mutool poster -x 4 -y 2 -r tempout1.pdf tempout2.pdf
mutool trim -b MediaBox -o final.pdf tempout2.pdf

These should produce similar cleaner A7 size pages.

I'm not gonna deal with these issues. Each a7 block have i'ts data defined within it, with no overlapping of any sort.

thanks. But if i define each A7 block in its own page, shouldn't i be able to iterate each page and read isolated content of each page?

Thanks. Visually it does what i expected. But iterate through each page as a single A7 unit of data is not happening. As i call getText through pdfBox or iText library it goes as an A4 format! If i use ctrl + c in the text on each page it works tough.

@K J Yes anon.pdf is exactly what i need. I open up the doc with iText and iterate through all pages and have data structure for each separate page in line order top to bottom.

Because I don't know what you really mean by "extract the data from each A7 area of each page because they're related", I start with proposing a solution that (at least) visually splits the single A$ pdf page into eight A7 ones, following this disposition:
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+

Basically, it crops the current page using a moving window and imports it into a page of the new document.
public void splitPdf(String pdfFileName) throws IOException {
  File pdfFile = new File(pdfFileName);
  File pdfTargetFile = new File(pdfFileName + ".a7.pdf");

  try (PDDocument pdfDocument = Loader.loadPDF(new RandomAccessReadBufferedFile(pdfFile));
      PDDocument pdfTargetDocument = new PDDocument(); ) {

    for (PDPage pdfPage : pdfDocument.getPages()) {
      PDRectangle cropBox = pdfPage.getCropBox();
      float upperRightX = cropBox.getUpperRightX();
      float upperRightY = cropBox.getUpperRightY();
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
          float cropLowerLeftX = upperRightX / 4 * j;
          float cropUpperRightX = upperRightX / 4 * (j + 1);
          float cropLowerLeftY = upperRightY / 2 * i;
          float cropUpperRightY = upperRightY / 2 * (i + 1);
          cropBox.setLowerLeftX(cropLowerLeftX);
          cropBox.setUpperRightX(cropUpperRightX);
          cropBox.setLowerLeftY(cropLowerLeftY);
          cropBox.setUpperRightY(cropUpperRightY);
          pdfPage.setCropBox(cropBox);
          pdfTargetDocument.importPage(pdfPage);
        }
      }
    }
    
    pdfTargetDocument.save(pdfTargetFile);
  }
}

Anyway, this is not really a "splitting", since in fact each page of the new document contains all the data of the original one, but it is just "bejond page borders", it's because of this I called this a "visual" splitting.

Thansk for the help. It is doing what i intended. But as i open the new doc with a page for each A7 block, as i read the content it is not reading as new pages, but it remebers the original layout as A4. Why is that? Here is the new doc: https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3.barcodegen-website.io/prog.pdf

Each page contains the whole A4 content, merely the area to display has been limited. Just like Francesco said.

OK i understand, just visual split, not data structure split. Any ideias how to achieve data structure splitting?

In general really complicated, in particular because structure elements may display across pages and, therefore, would have to be reworked.
